# Regex match space in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match

`Begin_Page {Some Number}`

while trying to avoid

`Begin_Page_{Some Number}`

I tried

`$line =~ m/^Begin_Page\s/`

but I noticed it sometimes does not match anything file while surely had `Begin_Page 8703`

Comment: But there's a space after begin_page and before \s

Comment: that was my typo, and its not in the code, sorry `corrected`

Comment: is `Begin_Page` in your file actually at the begining of the line?

Comment: does it match if you remove `\s` from your regex?

Comment: Are you sure there's exactly one space? You might change `\s` to `\s+` to match one or more spaces.

Comment: Maybe you need to show your input and how you are reading the lines of the file into `$line`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regexp is correct; the line should match:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^Begin_Page\s/) { print "OK: " }
    else                 { print "KO: " }
    print;
}
```

```
__DATA__
test
1233
Begin_Page 123
Begin_Page_456
Begin_Page 8703
```

Output:

```
KO: test
KO: 1233
OK: Begin_Page 123
KO: Begin_Page_456
OK: Begin_Page 8703
```

Comment: my bad guys there was unexpected `End_Page` in some files which was closing the loop in which I load data